# Text_area empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display the content of my message class using  text_area helper but when I load the page the text area is always blank.

```
<div id="messages">
<% for message in @channel.messages %>

      <h3><div class="title"><%=h message.description %></div></h3>
      <div class="moderator">Sent By: <%=h message.moderator %><br>On <%= message.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %></div>
      <div class="description">Channel Summary:<br><%= text_area("Message",  simple_format(message.content), :cols => 40, :disabled=> true, :rows => 10) %><!/div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **text_area_tag** helper in this case.
**text_area** is meant to be used when using **form_for**.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_area_tag

```
<%= text_area_tag("message",  simple_format(message.content), :cols => 40, :disabled=> true, :rows => 10) %>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can paginate this?

Comment: use will_paginate for that and move @channel.messages to the controller if possible

Comment: to the will_paginate controller?

Answer (score 1):

[api docs](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002393) say you use method incorrectly.
smth like that would be correct
    text_area(:message,  :content, :cols => 40, :disabled=> true, :rows => 10)

but if you want to call simple_format on content, use [text_area_tag instead](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002302).